# Php variable $id =$_GET('id') has value but not working within code

Tags: php, pdo, get

I am currently trying to make a basic website with php in which I can essentially edit blogs etc.. and when i9 double click the  current text I have made it so that an iframe popup opens for text to be changed. This iframe has a src of `editbox.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>`($id works for the parent page).

The problem is that the $Id in the code doesnrt seem to get recognised in the $query part even though it seems to have teh correct value

The code for the iframe page is below:

```
<?php

include_once('../includes/connection.php');
include_once('../includes/article.php');

$article = new Article;
$id =$_GET['id'];
print_r($id);

$data = $article->fetch_data($id);

if (isset($_POST['content'])) {
    $content = $_POST['content'];
    $uid =$_GET['id'];

    $query = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE articles SET article_content='$content' WHERE article_id='$id'");

    $query->execute();?>

    <script>parent.location.href=parent.location.href</script>

        <?php }?> 

<script>
function textAreaAdjust(element){
     element.style.height = "auto"
     element.style.height = (25+element.scrollHeight)+"px";
     }</script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="../Assets/style2.css" />    
<form action="editbox.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">    
<textarea autofocus="true" onfocus="textAreaAdjust(this);" onkeyup="textAreaAdjust(this)" cols="157" placeholder="Content" name="content" ><?php echo $data['article_content']?></textarea><br /><br />
<input type="Submit" value="Add article" />
</form>
```

What's strange is that the print_r returns a 3 which is what its supposed to return but for some reason it doesn't work.

Also it does work if I change it from `$id =$_GET('id')` to `$id=3` but since id is dynamic I cant do this.

Sorry if the code above has other problems, I'm a newbie.

Comment: _“This iframe has a src of `editbox.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>`”_ - originally. What is the URL after you submit your edit form though …?

Comment: Yes it does change and remove the id part after submitting. Is this the problem? If so how do I fix it?

Comment: _“Is this the problem?”_ - of course it is, what would you expect `$uid =$_GET['id'];` to contain now, if the parameter `id` was not set in the URL? Btw., PHP could alert you to the fact that you are trying to access stuff that is not set, on its own, if only you would let it - please go and enable proper PHP error reporting NOW! _“If so how do I fix it?”_ – well make sure that the form action includes the parameter again, same as the iframe src did to begin with.